# Python: syntax assignment error in iteration

Tags: python, syntax, iteration, counter

I am doing a simple script for self learning in python where the scripts in turn finds the 1000th prime number but I get a syntax error.

```
x = 0
y = 2
counter = x
integer = y
while (counter>999):
      if (y%2 == 0 or y%3 == 0):
          y = y + 1
      else:(counter = counter + 1 and integer = integer + 1)
print (y)
```

when it comes to the ='s assignment right after the ELSE operator and I don't understand why it won't let me add one to both the counter and integer when this has worked in other iteration scenario

Comment: 'and' doesn't mean 'also do this'. It means 'evaluate the boolean truth value of both expressions, and give a truth value only if both expressions evaluate to true.'

Comment: Please get rid of the parentheses. `while (counter>999):` should be `while counter < 999:` (including the correction of the logic error).

Comment: In addition to the comment by @MichaelKent, if you want to use muliple statements in one line, separate them with a semicolon `;`: `counter += 1; integer += 1` would increment both of these variables.

Comment: Thank you guys! but now with everything up to speed it just ends up spitting out 5 and not the 1000th prime

Comment: @AaronMerrifield You're testing if y%2 == 0. I think you meant to test if counter%2 == 0 instead. However, I'm not sure how you got your program logic... I don't see how it's meant to find the 1000th prime

Comment: well this is my thinking if the remainder of y/2 or 3 is 0 then the integer is not prime and I add 1 to y if it is prime I add one to both y and x increasing x's counter by 1 until it reaches its set limit

Comment: @AaronMerrifield That won't tell you if the number is prime or not. Wikipedia has [some algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization) to test it, but I'm not sure if they're within the scope of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can't make an assignment inside an expresion, to avoid misspellings between `=` and `==`. So you must do that in two lines:

```
x = 0
y = 2
counter = x
integer = y
while (counter>999):
    if (y%2 == 0 or y%3 == 0):
        y = y + 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        integer += 1
print (y)
```

Comment: Thank you! it got rid of my syntax error but then proceeds to only print out the original y instead of looping up to the while (counter<999) >.<

Comment: @AaronMerrifield Don't confuse `<` and `>`. If `counter` starts with `0`, it is not `> 999` and thus the `while` loop doesn't execute.

Comment: ah I see! thank you glglgl but now print just spits out 5! I'm sorry for being such a n00b I took this upon myself a mere 3 days ago

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   else:
      counter = counter + 1
      integer = integer + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! it got rid of my syntax error but then proceeds to only print out the original y instead of looping up to the while (counter<999) >.<

Comment: @AaronMerrifield That is because you check if `counter>999` in your while loop. In order to iterate from 1 to 999, you have to loop while `counter <= 999`

Comment: :) thank you! but know with everything all up to speed the scripts just ends up spitting out 5

Answer (score 0):

In python, assignment to variable has no Boolean value. and mean Boolean operator not do this and this.

so you need to split the statements.

```
x = 0
y = 2
counter = x
integer = y
while (counter>999):
    if (y%2 == 0 or y%3 == 0):
        y = y + 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        integer += 1
print (y)
```